# `DebugUndefined` in Jinja2 ignores missing iterable variables

Tags: python, jinja2

I need to catch all undefined variables in my template. To do that I'm using the `find_undeclared_variables()` function. The problem is, that it ignores missing iterables. See following example:

```py
import jinja2
from jinja2.meta import find_undeclared_variables

env = jinja2.Environment(undefined=jinja2.DebugUndefined)
template = env.from_string('{% for x in y %}{{x}}{% endfor %} - {{a}}, {{b}}')

rendered = template.render()

ast = env.parse(rendered)
undefined = find_undeclared_variables(ast)

print("undefined:", undefined)
```

The `undefined` variable will contain only `a` and `b` - variable `y` is not reported. When I change the `undefined` argument for `jinja2.Environment` to `StrictUndefined` the code crashes as the `y` is undefined:

```py
import jinja2
from jinja2.meta import find_undeclared_variables

env = jinja2.Environment(undefined=jinja2.StrictUndefined) # <<<< here is the only change
template = env.from_string('{% for x in y %}{{x}}{% endfor %} - {{a}}, {{b}}')

rendered = template.render()

ast = env.parse(rendered)
undefined = find_undeclared_variables(ast)

print("undefined:", undefined)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-file.py", line 7, in <module>
    rendered = template.render()
  File "/tmp/for-jinja/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/tmp/for-jinja/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/tmp/for-jinja/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'y' is undefined
```

Why the iterable is not captured as undeclared while it raises an exception in Strict mode?

Comment: "Why the iterable is not captured as undeclared" - By default, jinja2 doesn't treat iterating over `undefined` as a problem, and interprets this iteration as an iteration over empty sequence. Many project's relies on that feature. You may find more information in the Jinja documentation: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.Undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be ignored with `StrictUndefined`?

Comment: "Shouldn't it also be ignored with `StrictUndefined`?" - The documentation clearly states that `StrictUndefined` disallows iteration over `undefined`: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.StrictUndefined. That is, using `StrictUndefined` changes default Jinja semantic about allowed operations on `undefined`